# tkinter after method not working(Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to change a colour of a rectangle every 1 sec and for some reason only the last colour is used. Those in between aren't used at all. Where am I doing wrong? Here's my code -

```
class app():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()

        self.root.minsize(500, 500)
        self.root.maxsize(500, 500)
        self.counter = 4
        self.color = ["red","green","yellow","grey"]

        self.mainframe = Canvas(self.root, width=400, height=200)

        self.blue = self.mainframe.create_rectangle(20,20,120,60,fill='blue',width=0)

        self.mainframe.pack()

        Button(self.root,text="press",command=self.click).pack()


       self.root.mainloop() 

def click(self):
    self.root.after(1000,self.__timer)

def __timer(self):
    if self.counter > 0:
        for i in range(self.counter):
            self.mainframe.itemconfigure(self.blue_button,fill=self.color[i])
            self.root.after(1000,self.__timer)    
            self.counter -= 1
```

Comment: what is the initial color of the thing? (before red). Is it grey? If yes then I think it might be that click isn't being called... put in some debug print statements to see if stuff is getting called when you think it should be

Answer (score 1):

Your timer function is trying to set the color of `self.blue_button` but there is no such object. Did you intend to change the color of `self.blue`?

Also, you have a logic problem. Take a look at this code:

```
if self.counter > 0:
    for i in range(self.counter):
        self.mainframe.itemconfigure(self.blue_button,fill=self.color[i])
        self.root.after(1000,self.__timer)    
        self.counter -= 1
```

Notice how you are decrementing `self.counter` inside the loop. Thus, the first time `__timer` is called, it will set `self.counter` to zero once it has finished. The second time that `__timer` is called one second later, `self.counter` is zero and thus the loop is never entered.

Comment: You are right. I meant to change blue. But I found out that for some reason place timer method inside the loop doesn't work the way I wanted. I ended using recursive loop using the timer function itself.

Comment: @Andrew: I've updated my answer to explain why it's not working.